# change the labels and the styles in the okta-widget

Tags: reactjs, okta

I want to build a signin form that authenticate users using Okta and I used this code that works perfectly for me (https://github.com/leebrandt/okta-react-widget-sample).
However I want to have the controle on the form (change the title, the labels, the css ect.)

How may I do that ?

Answer (score -1):

The Sign-In Widget's reference guide includes information on how to change [language and text](https://github.com/okta/okta-signin-widget#language-and-text).